# "if" statement with "or" operator not working

Tags: c++

Trying to have my program make the user renter input if they choose a number that isn't 1 2 or 3.
 However whenever I type 1 2 or 3 it still wants me to re enter an integer. Did I use my or operator wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std; 

int main()
{

    cout << "Choose option 1,2 or 3: \n";
    cout << "1: Drop a single chip into one slot \n";
    cout << "2: Drop multiple chips into one slot \n";
    cout << "3: Quit the program \n";

    int choice;
    cin >> choice; 

    if  (choice != 1||2||3)
    {
        cout << "Please enter 1 2 or 3 \n";
        cin >> choice;
    }

        else 

            {
                cout << "it worked \n";
            }
}
```

Comment: `if (choice != 1||2||3)` should be `if (choice != 1 && choice != 2 && choice != 3)`

Answer (score 3):

Its because your `if`:

```
choice != 1||2||3
```

is evaluating to:

```
int != int|| true || true
```

And thats always true (something OR yes OR yes -> yes)

Every non-zero integer (`x!=0`) value casted to boolean will become `true`.

Its because humans and computers cant make decision on `1` number - you must change it to `true` or `false` (yes or no)

To resolve the problem simply change it to:

`if (choice != 1 && choice != 2 && choice != 3)`

EDIT:  Thanks to @StillLearning for improvements

Answer (score 3):

This condition in the if statement

```
if  (choice != 1||2||3)
```

is equivalent to

```
if  ( ( choice != 1 ) || 2 || 3 )
```

So it is always equal to `true` because even if `choice != 1`  evaluates to `false` nevertheless expressions `2` and `3` are always unequal to zero and consequently each of them evaluate to `true`.

What you mean is the following

```
if  ( ( choice != 1 ) && ( choice != 2 ) && ( choice != 3 ) )
```

Or you could write it simpler

```
if  ( choice < 1  || choice > 3 )
```

Or maybe this one will be more readable

```
if  ( !( 1 <= choice && choice <= 3 ) )
```

or even the following way:)

```
if  ( not ( 1 <= choice && choice <= 3 ) )
```

Take into account that you could this part of the program enclose in do-while loop. For example

```
int choice;
bool valid_input;

do
{
    cout << "Choose option 1,2 or 3: \n";
    cout << "1: Drop a single chip into one slot \n";
    cout << "2: Drop multiple chips into one slot \n";
    cout << "3: Quit the program \n";

    if ( !( cin >> choice ) ) break;

    valid-input  = 1 <= choice && choice <= 3;

    if  ( !valid_input )
    {
        cout << "Please enter 1 2 or 3 \n";
    }
} while ( !valid_input );

if ( valid_input )
{
    cout << "it worked. There was selected option " << choice << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Did I use my or operator wrong?

Yes.

> if  (choice != 1||2||3)

What this really does:

`if ((choice != 1) || (2) || (3))`

which is to say: "if choice does not equal 1 or true or true".

This is the same as doing `if (true)`.

What you want to do is:

`if (choice != 1 && choice != 2 && choice != 3) { ... re-enter number }`

Comment: Those are logical ORs, so it is really doing `if ((choice != 1) || (2) || (3))` (if that makes it any clearer than the original)

Answer (score -4):

You need this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Choose option 1,2 or 3: \n";
    cout << "1: Drop a single chip into one slot \n";
    cout << "2: Drop multiple chips into one slot \n";
    cout << "3: Quit the program \n";

    int choice;
    cin >> choice; 

    if  (choice != 1 || choice != 2 || choice != 3)
    {
        cout << "Please enter 1 2 or 3 \n";
        cin >> choice;
    }
    else 
    {
        out << "it worked \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `||` with `&&`

Comment: I left the implementation how he defined it. I just wanted to show the correct usage of the `||` operator.

Comment: And for sure that wasn't what OP wanted to do. Your code always evaluates to true.